# How to inspect an object using pdb in python

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

How do I inspect what is contained in an object using pythons pdb.
To make it clear at the top of my file I have

```
from nose.tools import set_trace
```

then inside somewhere I have

```
set_trace()

result = some_function(request.common[some_argument)
```

Then I run using

```
nosetests mycode.py
```

How do I examine variables, and values contained in result. I do not want to dig into `some_function` of course.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: So you want us to dig into ? Ok. Once you get into pdb prompt, type `p result`.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean I did not want to dig into the documentation, but I meant not dig into some_function code to find what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with `nose.tools` but it seems like it's at least working enough to start the trace and breakpoint for you, although I think the way you would typically do this in Python (in 2023 at least) would be to import like this

```py
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

directly in your code wherever you feel like initializing your first breakpoint.

Once your breakpoint has been caught and you can interact with PDB via the command line (Once the prompt looks like `(Pdb)` ) you can start executing commands. The full list can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html in the official docs, but the ones i find myself typically using are

```
l - show the surrounding lines of code so you know where you are
ll - show a ton of the surrounding lines of code
n - proceed to the next line
s - enter the function you are currently on with the cursor
```

If you want to inspect an actual variable you can just type its name, so in your case you could just type either

```
result
```

or

```
pp dir(result)
```

if its an object whose attributes you want to see, and you would likely get the values inside!